# How to change the sheet below to notes?

Tags: scales

[image]

Hello,

The sheet above looks like a major scale, and the blue coloured are blue notes according to the source which is Wikipedia. But I don't know the notes. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: On what particular instrument? A lot more information might help this being closed.

Comment: I assume you got this image from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_note What do you mean by “I don’t know the notes”?

Comment: Yes, the picture is from the Wikipedia article of blue notes. What I mean is what are those notations stand for, did it start from C? If it started from C, what are the other notes? On what instruments? Preferably guitar and piano. Thanks.

Comment: This is standard music, for any instrument, and it's the basic C scale (black), with the addition of the blue (blue!) notes. It sounds like you're already in too deep if you can't read the notes on guitar and piano.

Comment: What are those notes after C? I'm curious. I just don't know what the notations stand for in the picture. I hope I can read sheet music though.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know what the flat ♭ natural ♮ and sharp ♯ signs mean?    You're not really giving us a lot to go on here...

Comment: Yes. thanks for that. And the notes the picture above represented. If it is C, what are the next notes?

Comment: What instrument do you play? I can't think of an instrument where you would play from pitch letters only and not know how to read staff notation. Although some beginner music books put letters on the note heads. Guitar often uses tab instead of staff, but you don't need to know pitch letters for tab.

Comment: You're getting some weird responses because I *think* maybe you're asking "how do you play these notes on an instrument." But the answer to that will be different for every instrument. You play an E flat on a piano by looking for the black keys that make a group of two and playing the top one. You play it on a guitar with the 4th fret on the second string. But you also have to get the right "copy" of an E flat; this treble clef staff means you can't just pick any of the sets-of-2-black-keys on piano, but a specific one...

Comment: Also, you should read the article on "blue note" carefully, or look up other sources if it doesn't make sense: One of the most important things about the blue note is that it's not fixed to these exact pitches. These blue notes might be tuned slightly higher or lower than piano keys, or might "bend" or change during the note. Talking about "blue notes" is talking about blues, and that means the conventions of the genre.

Comment: @AndyBonner the question appears not to be asking how to play anything but simply how to read staff notation.  The third comment for example may be paraphrased "is the first note C, and what are the other notes?"  Notice that the accepted answer simply answers that question.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, I was looking at all the comments for context too. "If it started from C, what are the other notes? On what instruments? Preferably guitar and piano."

Comment: Awalrod already give the answer, it is C, D, E flat, E, F, F sharp, G, A, B flat, B and C. I'm self-taught so I can't read musical sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black notes are the C major scale: C D E F G A B (C)
The "blue" notes are Eb F#/Gb Bb
These blue notes are the minor third, tritone, and flat seventh, respectively. Idiomatic color notes to the blues/jazz tradition.

Note that in a different key, these blue notes will be different.

Learning to read music enough to work out note names and locations on guitar/piano is not as hard as you may think. It may benefit you to spend a few hours learning the basics of reading through youtube or a similar platform.

Comment: Thank you so much, Awalrod. Much appreciated. I will, thanks for the recommendation.